# UNIX: Convert Unix Date in Specific format

Tags: date, unix, solaris

I have some date other than current date in unix and I want to convert into a specific format

```
Original Format
D="Mon Dec 30 06:35:02 EST 2013"

New Format
E=20131230063502
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

this is the way to format the output of the date command and save it in the variable E

Answer (score 0):

Using python:

```
def data(dstr):
    m = {'Jan': '01', 'Feb':'02', 'Mar':'03', 'Apr':'04', 'May':'05', 'Jun':'06', 'Jul':'07', 'Aug':'08', 'Sep':'09', 'Oct':'10', 'Nov':'11', 'Dec':'12'}
    val = dstr.split(' ')
    month = m[val[1]]
    time = val[3].split(':')
    return '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(val[-1],month,val[2],time[0],time[1],time[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print data("Mon Dec 30 06:35:02 EST 2013")
```

In: `Mon Dec 30 06:35:02 EST 2013`

Out: `20131230063502`